# Wordpress single page ReWrite to root directory - htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have wordpress installed in a subdirectory, I plan on keeping it in the subdirectory but I want a URL in the root to rewrite for a **single** Wordpress page.

So far what's happening when I try the following code in htaccess it's making a redirect instead, even if I turn off Wordpress' permalinks.

```
#RewriteRule about /wordpress/?p=446 [L]
```

redirects to http://example/wordpress/?p=446

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is what is meant here.

```
RewriteRule ^(about)($|/) /wordpress/?p=446 [L]
```

This line must appear before the other RewriteRule lines.

Comment: Still redirecting rather than rewriting.
I'm thinking it has something to do with how wordpress cleans up urls...

Comment: Please, try wordpress/?p=446. Without the leading slash(/).